# How to bind RSS to a repeater control in ASP.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

What is the correct procedure to bind RSS FEED in Repeater control in ASP.NET? need with Aspx page design code and Aspx.cs code.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?ix=hcb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=bind%20rss%20to%20repeater%20asp.net) should find you plenty of options.

Heres one for example:

http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2008/06/21/3469.aspx

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="false" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Xml" %>
<script runat="server" language="C#">
    public string rssUrl = "http://blogs.x2line.com/al/rss.aspx";
    private System.Xml.XmlDocument doc;

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(rssUrl);

        base.DataBind();
    }

    public void Page_Load(System.Object s, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataBind();
    }
</script>

<asp:Repeater 
    runat="server" 
    id="rptrRss" 
    DataSource='< %# doc.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item[position()<=5]") %>'>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div>
            <a href='<%# doc.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/image/link").InnerText %>'>
            <img 
                src='<%# doc.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/image/url").InnerText %>' 
                alt='<%# doc.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/image/title").InnerText %>' />
            </a>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a 
            href='< %# (Container.DataItem as XmlNode)["link"].InnerText %>'>
            <%# (Container.DataItem as XmlNode)["title"].InnerText %>
            (<%# (Container.DataItem as XmlNode).SelectSingleNode("author |
title[not(../author)]").InnerText %>)
        < /a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate> 
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```